Does Rust have something equivalent to R's str()?
In R, a scripting/interpreted language, we have str(some_object) which gives a high level summary or overview of the nature of some_object in the workspace, including a small sample of entries stored within.  This is very helpful in understanding the object and what one can do with it, access its inner parts and so forth.  Here's an example:
> data(CO2)
> str(CO2)
Classes ‘nfnGroupedData’, ‘nfGroupedData’, ‘groupedData’ and 'data.frame':  84 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Plant    : Ord.factor w/ 12 levels "Qn1"<"Qn2"<"Qn3"<..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ Type     : Factor w/ 2 levels "Quebec","Mississippi": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Treatment: Factor w/ 2 levels "nonchilled","chilled": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ conc     : num  95 175 250 350 500 675 1000 95 175 250 ...
 $ uptake   : num  16 30.4 34.8 37.2 35.3 39.2 39.7 13.6 27.3 37.1 ...
 - attr(*, "formula")=Class 'formula'  language uptake ~ conc | Plant
  .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_EmptyEnv> 
 - attr(*, "outer")=Class 'formula'  language ~Treatment * Type
  .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_EmptyEnv> 
 - attr(*, "labels")=List of 2
  ..$ x: chr "Ambient carbon dioxide concentration"
  ..$ y: chr "CO2 uptake rate"
 - attr(*, "units")=List of 2
  ..$ x: chr "(uL/L)"
  ..$ y: chr "(umol/m^2 s)"

The help file for str describes it as

Compactly display the internal structure of an R object, a diagnostic
function and an alternative to summary (and to some extent, dput).
Ideally, only one line for each ‘basic’ structure is displayed. It is
especially well suited to compactly display the (abbreviated) contents
of (possibly nested) lists. The idea is to give reasonable output for
any R object. It calls args for (non-primitive) function objects.

One can write methods to be used with str for any given class but if no method exists for an object it does a pretty good job anyway.
I'm learning Rust and I am wondering if Rust has an equivalent function, a function that could be called to display/print an overview of any variable in scope.

Debug?

@ChayimFriedman do you mean using something like println!("{:?}", some_object); ?  This seems to give the entire contents of some_object and no indication of classes, types etc.

Sounds like the rest is covered by documentation (either on docs.rs or generated locally with cargo doc). Rust doesn't embed documentation in the executable code.

If an object (all of it or a snippet) were labeled with its type/class/whatever then it would be much faster to find the relevant documentation, especially when early on the learning curve.  The thing about str() is it allows one to reverse engineer quickly.

I don't think anyone would argue with that on its own, but Rust is a compiled language and thus works differently. You generally don't discover what you can do with a type by inspecting it at runtime in Rust; all types are known statically and thus are inspect-able by your IDE without running the code.

Maybe I'm missing a plug-in for my IDE, which is Visual Studio Code.

And I need to adjust my mental paradigm!

Without any plugin, there's always the Simpson hack: try to compile let _:()=some_object; and the error message will give you the type of some_object.

@Jmb Thanks I'm going to try to use that.

Closest I can think of an equivalent is the dbg!() macro. Everything else gets covered by the Type and the documentation. Take a look at the macro here https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.dbg.html

Debug output usually does include the type name, so I'm a little confused by your statement to the contrary. The exception is primitive values and containers.

Thanks @Anshul I didn't realize there was a debug macro, I thought "{:?} was the only way.  I will experiment.
